# Run Time Error 438 but macro works fine, how do I get rid or move past error?

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error, excel-2013

I'm getting an error 438 Run Time error when running the following simple code, the italicized code is where the error is highlighted, but my sheet name and header update fine. Is there a way I can either solve the error or simply move past the error without interrupting the macro?

```
Sub RenameSheet()

ActiveSheet.Name = Range("B2").Value
ActiveSheet.CenterHeader = ActiveSheet.Name '<~~ error here

End Sub
```

Comment: `on error resume next` will move past it but that is not good practice.  If you have an error you should handle that error

Comment: @Sorceri I agree, I'm confused because the macro completes both actions but I'd like to solve if I can!

Comment: Activesheet does not have a CenterHeader, PageSetup does: `ActiveSheet.PageSetup.CenterHeader` : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/pagesetup-centerheader-property-excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error 438 means you're invoking a member that doesn't exist.

`ActiveSheet` is a property of `Application` that returns an `Object`, which means any member calls you make against it are going to be late-bound, i.e. VBA runtime needs to query `IDispatch` and locate the member on the object's vtable - in other words you can't get IntelliSense for any of such member calls, and any typo will happily compile.

Declare a `Worksheet` object instead of working directly off `ActiveSheet`:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
```

Then you get compile-time validation of everything you call against it, and IntelliSense to guide you through your member calls.

The `CenterHeader` property is a member of the `PageSetup` object:

```
ws.PageSetup.CenterHeader = ws.Name
```